# A scripting language for legacy hardware

Tags: script, 16-bit

I want to pick up a scripting language for *real* legacy hardware. It must be compilable for 16-bit. What may suffice?

Comment: What type of os?

Comment: And what do you mean by *real* legacy hardware (just curious)

Comment: The OS is Minix. It is 80286.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) can be considered a scripting language, but it was born on 16-bit systems and compilers still exist for 16-bit.

There are several downloadable 16-bit Forth compilers on the [Forth Compilers Page](http://www.forth.org/compilers.html).

For instance Tom Zimmer's FPC V3.6, Forth (16-bit) for MS-DOS. [Download](ftp://ftp.taygeta.com/pub/Forth/Compilers/native/dos/FPC/fpc36.zip) (1.1 MB).

Answer (score 1):

- [Perl 3 for MS-DOS and Intel 8088 compatibles](http://www.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/sw/ports/dosperl/) by [Diomidis Spinellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20520/diomidis-spinellis)
- [Bourne shell for DOS](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms_sh23b.zip)
- Old versions of the [MKS Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_Toolkit) are available for DOS
- [Smalltalk is available for dos](http://forum.world.st/Looking-for-old-Smalltalks-for-DOS-td60531.html) but it's probably payware

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends what you mean by 16-bit - what hardware and OS are you meaning?

Assuming that you mean a 16-bit PC platform running MSDOS/DRDOS/FreeDOS/similar then you could try [4DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4DOS) which replaces command.com and adds, amongst many useful features, additional constructs to batch file processing.

I've not used it since the early/mid 90s, but the wikipedia page suggests it is still going and there is a free version that can be used with FreeDOS.